# magento 2 catalog_product_collection_load_before event

Tags: magento2, category-products, out-of-stock

I am using Magento Enterprise 2.2.10 and I am wanting to show out of stock products and want to have show at the end of the category collection.  I thought I could use the event: `catalog_product_collection_load_before` but that does not seem to exist in Magento 2 but this event does work: `catalog_product_collection_load_after`

If I use the `catalog_product_collection_load_after` event I can add the fields to the collection ordering but they get added the order default category ordering and does not accomplish what I want to do.

Any ideas how I can go ordering products like this since that event does not fire?

Is there a way to replace the order by query instead of add to it?

Using the event catalog_product_collection_load_after I was able to modify the collection query to order the data the way I want but it does not have any affect on the display of the products in the category.

This is what I came up with which does generate the correct query but why does it not change the order of the product on the category?

```
$collection                           
    ->getSelect()                     
    ->joinLeft(                       
        array('_inventory_table' => $c
        "_inventory_table.product_id =
        array('is_in_stock')          
    )                                 
    ->reset('order')                  
    ->order('is_in_stock DESC')       
    ->order('cat_index_position ASC');
```

Comment: I got this working by overriding the Magento catalog model layer instead of using the  event

Comment: please update your answer

Comment: Hi Trevor, can you update your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me.

```
public function afterGetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject, $result)
{
    $fieldOrders = $result->getSelect()->getPart('order');
    $curOrders = array();

    foreach($fieldOrders as $fieldOrder) {
        if ($fieldOrder[0] !== 'is_salable') {
            $curOrder = $fieldOrder[0];
            if (count($curOrder) > 1) {
                $curOrder .=  ' ' . $fieldOrder[1];
            }

            array_push($curOrders, $curOrder);              
        }
    }

    $result
        ->getSelect()
        ->reset('order')
        ->order('is_salable DESC');

    foreach($curOrders as $curOrder) {
        $result
            ->getSelect()
            ->order($curOrder);
    }

    return $result;
}
```